# using jquery dialog for java applet instead of windows.open with parameters

Tags: jquery, jquery-dialog

I'm struggling to figure out how to change my java applet to open inside a jquery dialog (if that's even possible). I have the following code to open up in a separate window:

```
 function launch(user, pass, name, hash, port) 
 {
     var generator=window.open('','','location=no,menubar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,status=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,width=425,height=400');
     generator.document.write('<html><head><title>Applet</title></head><body>');
     generator.document.write('\x3Cscript src="https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js">\x3C/script>\x3Cscript>');
     generator.document.write('var attributes = {code:"com.project.MyApplet", width:400, height:375};');
     generator.document.write('var parameters = {jnlp_href: "http://'+window.location.host+'/applications/MyApplet.jnlp", user: "'+user+'", pass: "'+pass+'", name: "'+name+'", hash: "'+hash+'", port: "'+port+'"};');
     generator.document.write('deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, "1.6");');
     generator.document.write('\x3C/script></body></html>');
     generator.document.close();
 }
```

I'd like to change this to open up in a jquery dialog. I could put this in an html file but then I'd still have the problem of passing all the parameters to this file:

```
 var $div = $('<div title="Java Applet"></div>');
    $div.load('applet.html', function() {
        $div.dialog({autoOpen: false});
    });
```

Any thoughts on how I can tackle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I've been able to get this to work is to create an iframe. See here for a follow up question I had on iframes to see what was done.

[Add javascript to iframe src attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324619/add-javascript-to-iframe-src-attribute)